# I grew an array with mdadm but I can't see the progress?

Tags: raid, mdadm

Today I added a 5th drive in my array, I did the following:

```
mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdf1
```

My drive was added as a spare, I then did:

```
mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --raid-devices=5
```

But when I want to check the progress with

```
watch cat /proc/mdstat
```

it gets stuck and I can't see what's going on. Meanwhile, I can't access the data wich I assume or hope is normal. Any ideas?